# How to get time difference in hours in a custom date format in Go

Tags: date, go, time, format

I need help with comparison this type of format date help and I want to print a comparison delay by hours

```
createdAt := msg.Header.Get("Date") // string: Sun, 03 May 2020 16:37:40 +0000 (UTC)

t, err := time.Parse("i don't have this", createdAt)

if err != nil {
    fmt.Println(err)
}

// some code here idk - comparison createdAt with date/time now

fmt.Printf("Lifespan is %+v", diff)
```

output:

```
Lifespan is 3h
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`net/http`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/) package has a helper function exactly for parsing times from headers, trying all HTTP-compliant formats: [`http.ParseTime()`](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#ParseTime). So you should definitely try that.

```
t, err := http.ParseTime(createdAt)
if err != nil {
    // Handle error
}

if t.Before(time.Now()) {
    fmt.Println("It's in the past")
} else {
    fmt.Println("It's in the future")
}
```

There's a catch though: your time doesn't seem to be in a valid HTTP/1.1 time format, but rather described by the following layout:

```
"Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)"
```

So you may parse it like:

```
t, err := time.Parse("Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700 (MST)", createdAt)
if err != nil {
    panic(err) // Handle error
}

delta := time.Since(t)
fmt.Println("Time since createdAt:", delta)
if delta < 0 {
    fmt.Println("It's in the past")
} else {
    fmt.Println("It's in the future")
}
```

It outputs (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Q5CxrMoGGlz)):

```
Time since createdAt: -91841h37m40s
It's in the past
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a format string to parse string to get `time.Time` type data

```
createdAt := "Sun, 03 May 2020 16:37:40 +0000  (UTC)"
format := "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 +0000  (MST)"
t, err := time.Parse(format, createdAt)
```

To get the duration between two date use `.Sub()` function which return duration in `time.Duration` type. And to get the duration in hour use `.Hours()` function of `time.Duration`.

```
now := time.Now()
diff := now.Sub(t)
fmt.Printf("Lifespan is %f", diff.Hours())
```

Full code in go playground [here](https://play.golang.com/p/7bEj2wabW_g)